# Gallery of pictures from distant site - Android

Tags: android

I need to add gallery to my android app. I used gallery in standard way, when pictures are in my folder, but now I need to show pictures when I have just pictures URLs(pictures are on some distant server). How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the server yours?

You might need to make an API to get the images from the server served to you.

Comment: I have site on that server and pictures is from that site. I can return pictures from web service or return url of picture, that is not problem, but do I need to download pictures and then in code set gallery or I can on some way just set url in gallery ?

Comment: How about this? http://evancharlton.com/thoughts/lazy-loading-images-in-a-listview/ or this? http://www.anddev.org/gallery_with_remote_images-t769.html

Comment: Thanks men, the second is solution to my problem!